# Adding custom codec to CassandraConnector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

Is there a way to register custom codecs on instantiation of `CassandraConnector`?

I am currently registering my codecs each time I call `cassandraConnector.withSessionDo`

```
val cassandraConnector = CassandraConnector(ssc.sparkContext.getConf)
...
...
.mapPartitions(partition => {
  cassandraConnector.withSessionDo(session => {
    // register custom codecs once for each partition so it isn't loaded as often for each data point
    if (partition.nonEmpty) {
      session.getCluster.getConfiguration.getCodecRegistry
        .register(new TimestampLongCodec)
        .register(new SummaryStatsBlobCodec)
        .register(new JavaHistogramBlobCodec)
    }
```

It seems a bit like an anti pattern to do it this way. It also really clogs up our logs because we have a spark streaming service that is running every 30 seconds and it's filling our logs with:

```
16/11/01 14:14:44 WARN CodecRegistry: Ignoring codec SummaryStatsBlobCodec [blob <-> SummaryStats] because it collides with previously registered codec SummaryStatsBlobCodec [blob <-> SummaryStats]
16/11/01 14:14:44 WARN CodecRegistry: Ignoring codec JavaHistogramBlobCodec [blob <-> Histogram] because it collides with previously registered codec JavaHistogramBlobCodec [blob <-> Histogram]
16/11/01 14:14:44 WARN CodecRegistry: Ignoring codec TimestampLongCodec [timestamp <-> java.lang.Long] because it collides with previously registered codec TimestampLongCodec [timestamp <-> java.lang.Long]
```

Edit:

I've tried registering them immediately like this:

```
val cassandraConnector = CassandraConnector(ssc.sparkContext.getConf)
cassandraConnector.withClusterDo(cluster => {
  cluster.getConfiguration.getCodecRegistry
    .register(new TimestampLongCodec)
    .register(new SummaryStatsBlobCodec)
    .register(new JavaHistogramBlobCodec)
})
```

This ^ works locally but when deployed to our mesos cluster, it can't find the codecs.  I'm assuming it's cause it only registers those locally in the driver, and never adds them to the executors version.

Comment: why don't you register them only once, e.g. after instantiating th connector? they are getting registered in the session, so if you reuse it you should be fine.

Comment: I thought I had added something about this in my question, sorry.  I've edited my question.  Is that how you meant to register them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The better way is to override cassandra connection factory, something like this

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.{CassandraConnectionFactory, CassandraConnectorConf, DefaultConnectionFactory}
object MyConnectionFactory extends CassandraConnectionFactory {
  override def createCluster(conf: CassandraConnectorConf): Cluster = {
    val cluster = DefaultConnectionFactory.createCluster(conf)
    cluster.getConfiguration.getCodecRegistry
      .register(new TimestampLongCodec)
      .register(new SummaryStatsBlobCodec)
      .register(new JavaHistogramBlobCodec)
    cluster
  }
}
```

and set `spark.cassandra.connection.factory` parameter to point to the class

Comment: I really like this answer.  Thanks for the help.